# Issue with Forest in MarkLogic after MarkLogic downgrade

Tags: marklogic, database-backups, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

Recently we updated from ML-7.03 to ML - 8.07, but ran into some issues and had to revert back to ML-7. Unfortunately when we took the backup of the entire ML directory which had ML-7, we didn't realize that the forest data was not part of the installation directory. As such when we have reverted back to ML-7, we are seeing the following error.

> XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in startup of forest "ABC-DE-001": XDMP-CORRUPT: read D:\Forest\Forests\ABC-DE-001\00003980: File corrupt, bad triple value index version, version=1

Please suggest what could have gone wrong, and how to fix this issue, as we don't have the backup of ML-7 with us to fall back to.

Regards
Amit

Answer (score 2):

[Downgrades are not supported](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/34/0/marklogic-server-version-downgrades-are-not-supported).

If you have access to MarkLogic Support, I would suggest creating a support ticket to discuss what issues you had with 8.0.7 and whether you can find a way to  move forward with 8.0.7. You would generally always want to use the most recent versions, especially after upgrading the data and lack a backup from the previous version.

If that turns out not to be feasible, they can help investigate alternative methods of extracting the data from your 8.0.7 forests and trying to load back into 7.0.3. For instance, using [MLCP Direct Access](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/extract) to extract documents from the 8.0.7 forests into an archive and then import the archive into 7.0.3.

Comment: Is it possible to take the backup of the Data Directory where the forest resides in the older version, and then use the same Data directory again later with older version? By backup I mean if I zip the entire Data directory of ML 7, and when I move back to ML 7 from ML 8 , I just unzip the Data directory and everything works fine as expected? I know ML admin has the option to take the backup of each database, but if I do it manually, should it work?